# Java default modifier in compilation

Tags: java, javac

I'm currently working on modifying javac compiler to produce, in a certain way, our own Programming Language.

We want to get rid of Java's default access modifier, making everything that has no access modifier as public.

But so far, I haven't been successfull to find where in Java compilation code this is implemented. I could easily add into one of the declaration phases, but this is a poor solution that we wouldn't like to have.

Any insight on this?

Comment: For interfaces, the default modifer is public. What I prefer to do is make everything private or perhaps package local and when I try to use something which requires public, let the IDE promote the field or method as an auto-fix (I have to have access to the source to do this)

Comment: (I have to ask: why would you make a change to the language like that?!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at [*The `class` File Format*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-4.html), especially section *4.5 Fields* and *4.6 Methods* I see the following constants being defined:

```
ACC_PUBLIC     0x0001
ACC_PRIVATE    0x0002
ACC_PROTECTED  0x0004
```

> However, a specific method (*field*) of a class may have at most one of its ACC_PRIVATE, ACC_PROTECTED, and ACC_PUBLIC flags set (JLS [§8.3.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.1)).

Since there is no `ACC_DEFAULT` flag and the documentation says *at **most** one* (not *exactly one*) I would guess that having no flags at all means default access.

Comment: So, we can assume there's no real attribution, and this is dealt only by jvm?

Comment: @Adriano: the modifiers *are* stored in the `.class` file and JVM reads them. I am only guessing that no `ACC_` modifers mean default modifier.